# C++ Calling a virtual method from a multiply inherited template class

Tags: c++, templates, multiple-inheritance, variadic-templates

I have a lot of code here but I'm afraid this is as little code as I could put to convey the problem, so please bear with me:

```
#include <iostream>

#define ASINSTANCE(x, type, y)                                                 \
    type * y = dynamic_cast<type *>(&(x));                                     \
    if (y)

class Fruit {
    virtual void a() = 0; // This is to surpress the "Fruit isn't polymorphic" we'd otherwise get.
};

class Apple : public Fruit {
    virtual void a() {

    }
};

class Orange : public Fruit {
    virtual void a() {

    }
};

class Banana : public Fruit {
    virtual void a() {

    }
};

template<typename FruitType>
class FruitEater {

protected:
    virtual void eat(const FruitType & t) = 0;

};

template<typename... FruitTypes>
class MultiFruitEater : public FruitEater<FruitTypes>... {

public:
    // Eat any fruit if it belongs to FruitTypes (returns false otherwise).
    bool dispatchEat(const Fruit & fruit);

private:
    template<typename First>
    bool dispatchEatByType(const Fruit & fruit);

    template<typename First, typename Second, typename... Rest>
    bool dispatchEatByType(const Fruit & fruit);

};

class MyEater : public MultiFruitEater<Apple, Orange, Banana> {

protected:
    virtual void eat(const Apple & t);
    virtual void eat(const Orange & t);
    virtual void eat(const Banana & t);
};

void MyEater::eat(const Apple & t) {
    std::cout << "Ate apple." << std::endl;
}
void MyEater::eat(const Orange & t) {
    std::cout << "Ate orange." << std::endl;
}
void MyEater::eat(const Banana & t) {
    std::cout << "Ate banana." << std::endl;
}

template<typename... FruitTypes>
bool MultiFruitEater<FruitTypes...>::dispatchEat(const Fruit & fruit) {
    return dispatchEatByType<FruitTypes...>(fruit);
}

template<typename... FruitTypes>
template<typename First>
bool MultiFruitEater<FruitTypes...>::dispatchEatByType(const Fruit & fruit) {
    ASINSTANCE(fruit, const First, pCastFruit) {
        eat(*pCastFruit);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

template<typename... FruitTypes>
template<typename First, typename Second, typename... Rest>
bool MultiFruitEater<FruitTypes...>::dispatchEatByType(const Fruit & fruit) {
    ASINSTANCE(fruit, const First, pCastFruit) {
        eat(*pCastFruit);
        return true;
    }
    return dispatchEatByType<Second, Rest...>(fruit);
}

int main() {
    MyEater eater;
    Banana b;
    eater.dispatchEat(b);
}
```

The problem is with the line:

```
eat(*pCastFruit);
```

I'm getting the following errors:

- error C2385: ambiguous access of 'eat'
- error C3861: 'eat': identifier not found

I tried replacing the line with:

```
this->FruitEater<First>::eat(*pCastFruit);
```

The errors now changed to:

- error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual
  void __thiscall FruitEater::eat(class Apple const &)"
  (?eat@?$FruitEater@VApple@@@@MAEXABVApple@@@Z) referenced in function
  "private: bool __thiscall MultiFruitEater::dispatchEatByType(class Fruit const &)"
  (??$dispatchEatByType@VApple@@VOrange@@VBanana@@@?$MultiFruitEater@VApple@@VOrange@@VBanana@@@@AAE_NABVFruit@@@Z)
- error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual
  void __thiscall FruitEater::eat(class Banana const &)"
  (?eat@?$FruitEater@VBanana@@@@MAEXABVBanana@@@Z) referenced in
  function "private: bool __thiscall MultiFruitEater::dispatchEatByType(class Fruit
  const &)"
  (??$dispatchEatByType@VBanana@@@?$MultiFruitEater@VApple@@VOrange@@VBanana@@@@AAE_NABVFruit@@@Z)

Any ideas?

Comment: What happens if you change your calls to `eat()` into:         `FruitEater<First> &fe = *this;
        fe.eat(*pCastFruit);`? (You will need to change the code to allow access to the method.)

Comment: I got clarification about why this is happening. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26374116/315052).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Resolution:

So I got your reponse:

Using Your define ASSISTANCE : (as you gess the type you now send isn't const

```
#define ASINSTANCE(x, type, y, eater)                                   \
  const type * y = dynamic_cast<const type *>(&(x));                    \
  FruitEater<type>* eater = dynamic_cast<FruitEater< type >*>(this);    \
  if (y && eater)
```

In your fruitEater class: (it let your multieater acccess to the eat methode

```
template<typename FruitType>
class FruitEater {

 protected:
  template<typename... Fruit> friend class MultiFruitEater;
  virtual void eat(const FruitType & t) = 0;

};
```

How to use your new ASSISTANCE define:

```
  ASINSTANCE(fruit, First, pCastFruit, eater) {
    eater->eat(*pCastFruit);
    return true;
  }
```

## Explanation: (not as precise as i would want)

I think the problem by doing this (`this->FruitEater<First>::eat(*pCastFruit);`), is you force the compiler to use the FruitEater::eat() methode, wich is a virtual void...

Comment: This worked except now, as jxh said, we're accessing eat (a protected method) on an allegedly different object, so we're denied access. Resolved by making MultiFruitEater a friend of FruitEater.

Comment: @saarraz1 isn't what i done? I didn't understood what you mean

Comment: This solved the problem perfectly, it only introduced another minor error (there's nothing wrong with your solution, don't worry (:  )

Comment: lol thanks, the error (as I said in the first comment) is that we can't access the eat method because its protected and we're accessing it through a pointer which is not this. I solved this by making MultiFruitEater a friend of FruitEater.