# Calling virtual method of base template from derived variadic template class

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, polymorphism, variadic-templates

This is essentially a follow-up to [an earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26351963/315052) (not posed by me, but I am interested in an answer).

*The question is:* ***Why does the compiler/linker fail to resolve the call to the virtual function from the derived class?*** In this case, the derived class is a template class with variadic parameters that applies multiple inheritance against the same template class multiple times (once for each type in the variadic parameters).

In the concrete example below, the derived class is `JobPlant`, and it is being called from `Worker`. Invoking the abstract `work()` method fails to link, while invoking `workaround()` links and executes in the expected way.

These are the link failures as shown by [ideone](http://ideone.com/mxfoKd):

```
/home/g6xLmI/ccpFAanK.o: In function `main':
prog.cpp:(.text.startup+0x8e): undefined reference to `Work<JobA>::work(JobA const&)'
prog.cpp:(.text.startup+0xc9): undefined reference to `Work<JobB>::work(JobB const&)'
prog.cpp:(.text.startup+0xff): undefined reference to `Work<JobC>::work(JobC const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

[Follow this link](http://ideone.com/yDaBSf) for demonstration of the workaround working.

`Job` is an abstract base class, and it has associated derived classes. `Work` is an abstract template class that performs a job. `Worker` is a template that identifies the `JOB` and performs it (`struct` instead of `class` purely to reduce syntax clutter):

```
struct Job { virtual ~Job() {} };

struct JobA : Job {};
struct JobB : Job {};
struct JobC : Job {};

template <typename JOB>
struct Work {
    virtual ~Work() {}
    virtual void work(const JOB &) = 0;
    void workaround(const Job &job) { work(dynamic_cast<const JOB &>(job)); }
};

template <typename PLANT, typename... JOBS> struct Worker;

template <typename PLANT, typename JOB, typename... JOBS>
struct Worker<PLANT, JOB, JOBS...> {
    bool operator()(PLANT *p, const Job &job) const {
        if (Worker<PLANT, JOB>()(p, job)) return true;
        return Worker<PLANT, JOBS...>()(p, job);
    }
};

template <typename PLANT, typename JOB>
struct Worker<PLANT, JOB> {
    bool operator()(PLANT *p, const Job &job) const {
        if (dynamic_cast<const JOB *>(&job)) {
            p->Work<JOB>::work(dynamic_cast<const JOB &>(job));
            //p->Work<JOB>::workaround(job);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

A `JobPlant` is a template class parameterized by `JOBS`, that finds a `Worker` to perform a `job`. The `JobPlant` inherits from `Work` for each job type in `JOBS`. `MyJobPlant` is an instance of `JobPlant`, and implements the virtual `work` methods from the associated `Work` abstract classes.

```
template <typename... JOBS>
struct JobPlant : Work<JOBS>... {
    typedef Worker<JobPlant, JOBS...> WORKER;
    bool worker(const Job &job) { return WORKER()(this, job); }
};

struct MyJobPlant : JobPlant<JobA, JobB, JobC> {
    void work(const JobA &) { std::cout << "Job A." << std::endl; }
    void work(const JobB &) { std::cout << "Job B." << std::endl; }
    void work(const JobC &) { std::cout << "Job C." << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
    JobB j;
    MyJobPlant().worker(j);
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You explicitly call `p->Work<JOB>::work()`, that is, the pure virtual method in `Work<JOB>`. This method is not implemented (it's pure after all).

It doesn't matter that derived classes might have implemented/overridden that method. The `Work<JOB>::` says that you want the version from that class, not something from a derived class. No dynamic dispatch happens.

(`Work<JOB>::work()` is the syntax you would use to call a base class method from a overriding method in a derived class, and there you really want the base class method.)

---

When you remove then explicit `Work<JOB>::`, the result is an ambiguity error. When trying to resolve the name `work`, the compiler first tries to determine which of the base classes contains that name. After that, the next step then would be overload resolution amongst the different `work` methods in that class.

Unfortunately the first step results in ambiguity: more than one base class contains the name `work`. The compiler then never tries to figure out the matching overload. (They are not really overloads but conflicting with each other, since they are from different classes).

Usually this can be solved by bringing the base class method names into the derived class with `using` (or however it's technically called what `using` does). If you add `using` declarations for all the `work` methods of the base classes, the compiler finds the name `work` in the derived class (no ambiguity) and can then proceed with overload resolution (also not ambigious).

The variadic template complicates things since I don't think `using Work<JOBS>::work...;` is legal (and my compiler doesn't think so either). But if you compose the base classes "manually", all the work methods can be brought into the final class:

```
template <typename JOB, typename... JOBS>
struct CollectWork : Work<JOB>, CollectWork<JOBS...> {
   using Work<JOB>::work;
   using CollectWork<JOBS...>::work;
};

template <typename JOB>
struct CollectWork<JOB> : Work<JOB> {
   using Work<JOB>::work;
};

template<typename... JOBS>
struct JobPlant : CollectWork<JOBS...> {                                           
   using CollectWork<JOBS...>::work;
   typedef Worker<JobPlant, JOBS...> WORKER;
   bool worker(const Job &job) { return WORKER()(this, job); }
};
```

With this construct, the problematic `p->work(dynamic_cast<const JOB &>(job));` [compiles and runs successfully](http://ideone.com/bySbiG).

Comment: Huh. That was simple. Can you explain why calling `p->work(dynamic_cast<const JOB &>(job))` gives an ambiguity error? See: http://ideone.com/2vL57z

Comment: Replacing the 'p->Work<JOB>::work()' by following code also resolves the issue.
Work<JOB> &w = *p;
w.work(dynamic_cast<const JOB &>(job));

Comment: @JVApen: You are correct! I could just dispatch to the right `Work<>` before calling `work()`. However, I was interested keenly impressed with this answer that demonstrated how to get dispatching through the method to work, along with its explanation about why the naive approach fails.